# How to randomly select all numbers in a range?

Tags: delphi, list, pascal

In pascal, I want to randomly select a number between 1 and 50 that goes in a loop.  Each time a number is selected that number is removed until there is eventually no numbers left between 1 and 50 to select from and the loop ends.

how is something like this done in Pascal/Delphi?

Comment: Sounds like a lottery drawing... Please be more specific with your question providing your end goal, and by God please do some tiny bit of research yourself before asking other people to do your research for you. I'll spare you with this advise by not down-voting or voting to close.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this had to be closed. It is a valid question, IMO.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. SO reminds me more and more to authoritarian governments. Last time I said something like this my comment got deleted.

Comment: try this
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
r : integer;
begin
while listbox1.Items.Count<>0 do
begin
r:=random(listbox1.Items.Count);
listbox1.Items.Delete(r);
end;
end; i want try to help wiht simple code but sory my answer in this comment because your post has closed

Comment: I really disagree with this question being closed.

Answer (score 5):

This have to be pretty easy.

1. You start with an array of numbers from 1 to 50
2. In each iteration you select a random number between 1 and the number of elements of the array
3. You get that element out of the array
4. Go to the Step 2 until there's no more elements left in the array.

In code, it can look like this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  ARRAY_ELEMENTS = 50;

var
  SourceArray: array of Integer;
  Element: Integer;
  ValidElements: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  try
    //array initialization
    SetLength(SourceArray, ARRAY_ELEMENTS);
    for Element := Low(SourceArray) to High(SourceArray) do
      SourceArray[Element] := Element + 1;
    ValidElements := ARRAY_ELEMENTS;
    repeat
      //select a random element
      Element := Random(ValidElements);
      Writeln(SourceArray[Element]);
      //remove the element from the array
      SourceArray[Element] := SourceArray[ValidElements - 1];
      Dec(ValidElements);
    until ValidElements = 0;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

**Edited** after comments to improve performance by swapping the last array element with the poked one.

#### List example

I didn't noticed your [list](/questions/tagged/list) tag, so here's a list example:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Generics.Collections;

const
  LIST_ELEMENTS = 50;

var
  I: Integer;
  Element: Integer;
  SourceList: TList<Integer>;
begin
  Randomize;
  try
    SourceList := TList<Integer>.Create();
    try
      for I := 1 to LIST_ELEMENTS do
        SourceList.Add(I);
      repeat
        Element := Random(SourceList.Count);
        Writeln(SourceList[Element]);
        SourceList.Delete(Element);
      until SourceList.Count = 0;
    finally
      SourceList.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: I like the `TList<Integer>` example, but since the question is tagged just `Delphi` `Pascal` and `List`, I would assume compatibility with any Delphi version, which means the second example wouldn't work on earlier versions.

Comment: @Jerry, you have the Array example, which works on any Delphi version. I tend to add answers based on the features/classes I like, and I like the generic list over the old TList of pointers, so I will never use/abuse it again to store integers (or anything else). For me, that list is deprecated. But if you don't have a decent Delphi version, my example is not too hard to translate to that ancient class, if you know what are you doing. I let that exercise to the reader.

Comment: I've honestly never used the `TList<>`, only the `TList` its self for compatibility.

Comment: It is ages over the old TList. You never cast anything anymore and the code is more legible and elegant. I maintain some library code and I have to support D2007 (and now maybe I have to go down to D2006 again), so I don't always enjoy the generics support, but I always use it when I can.

Comment: I don't always use generics, but when I do, it saves lives.

Comment: @JerryDodge: you read too many lolcats...

Comment: Instead of using TList or anything like it, an dynarray is fine and always of the correct base type. But instead of moving all items above the removed item down, just keep a counter of the still valid items, swap the item to be removed with the the item at the current top of the valid items and then decrement the number of valid items. This greatly reduces the number of items that are moved around (I guess O(n) instead of O(n^2)).

Comment: In your first example, instead of condensing the array, you could take the last element of the array and put that in place you the element you randomly picked and make setlength the array 1 smaller, would save using the for next loop.

Comment: Pieter and @Rudy, I had followed your advise and changed the algorithm. I really was not thinking about performance when first wrote it, but now I think it is optimized.

Comment: @jachguate: I would not Delete() anything. I would simply shuffle the list (see my previous reply: that is, in effect the algorithm for an in-place shuffle) on the fly.